# What is the proper format/style for using and properly citing code in an APA paper?

Tags: style, citations, apa

I'm working on a paper that covers concurrency in Java, however to properly explain many concepts I feel code samples are basically needed.

However, I don't know how to properly cite code I've borrowed, or how to properly format code that I've written myself.

How is this accomplished?

Comment: I give an example at http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/980/what-is-the-key-reference-documentation-and-how-should-i-cite-bash/1007#1007 - the full answer really involves getting a copy of the APA style guide.

Comment: @CharlesStewart - Would you be willing to turn this into a full answer with a citation?

Answer (score 1):

APA offers the [following guidelines](http://www.usq.edu.au/library/referencing/apa-referencing-guide#Other_electronic_media) for citing a computer program/software/programming language (under the "Other electronic media" section):

> Reference list entries are not necessary for standard off-the-shelf software and programming languages.  Provide entries for specialized software or programs with limited distribution.
>
> In text, give the name of the software, the version number and year.
>
> Do not italicise the names of software, programs, or languages.
>
> If an individual has proprietary rights to the software, name him or her as the author; otherwise, treat such references as unauthored works.
>
> Immediately after the title and version, identify with a source type such as [Computer program], [Computer language], or [Computer software].
>
> If no version number is available, include the retrieval date.
>
> If the program can be downloaded or ordered from the web, give this information in the publisher position.
>
> Schoonjans, F. (2008). MedCalc Statistical Software (Version 9.5.2.0) [Computer software]. Retrieved from 3D2F.COM Software Directory: http://3d2f.com/programs/13-638-medcalc-statistical-software-download.shtml
>
> Accurate Personality Test [Computer software]. (2007). Retrieved June 19, 2008, from http://www.sharewareconnection.com/accurate-personality-test.htm
>
> Tools and applications.
>   CultureGPS lite (Version 1.13) [Computer software]. (2011). Retrieved from http://itunes.apple.com/app/culturegps-lite/id297051765?mt=8
>
> Pages (Version 1.5) [Computer software]. (2011). Retrieved from http://itunes.apple.com/us/pages/id361309726?mt=8&ls=1
>
> Scott, C. (2011). Treasure hunt - the interactive boardgame (Version 1.1) [Computer software]. Retrieved from http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/treasure-hunt-the-interactive/id4425986640?mt=8

Consider looking at [this page](http://uark.libguides.com/content.php?pid=155080&sid=1780817) for a few helpful tips too (not APA though).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can find what you want [In-Text Citations: Author/Authors](http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/560/03/) section, where they give additional rules for citing indirect sources, electronic sources, and sources without page numbers. I believe it would work for source code.

Comment: Do you mean the sections "Electronic Sources" and "Sources Without Page Numbers"? If so, let's quote that here in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To refer to the details of Proper citing code in an APA paper , here's a reference guide which may help you : 
http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/560/25/

Comment: Which part of it? There's nothing here about source code. The computer software part?